# Vuestic VueJs hide element on small devices

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuestic

I want to hide element if screensize is sm or xs using [vuestic](https://vuestic.dev/) vuejs framework.

```html
<div class="flex md4 sm4 xs0"></div>
<div class="flex v-line xs0 sm0 md1"></div>
<div class="flex md8 xs12"></div>
```

I just need to know what can we do instead of `xs0` or `sm0` here? Because they are not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taha Malik.

Vuestic UI provides breakpoint service that allows you to control every aspect of your application which depends on the window size.
[docs](https://vuestic.dev/en/services/breakpoints)

In your case try to use next example:

```
<template>
<div v-if="breakpoint.current!=='xs'>Hide on xs size</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useBreakpoint } from "vuestic-ui";

const breakpoint = useBreakpoint()
</script>
```